# How to disable InAppBrowser feature

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, inappbrowser

I am writing an android application with Phonegap and InApp Browser feature is automatically enabled.

How can i disable it?

I wanna use of my default browser on my phone.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need to add the `target='_blank'` attribute to your `<a>` links.

Or, in the older versions of Phonegap, you may need to handle the `onclick` event for all the links that should be open in the system browser and launch it using something like this:

```
window.open(this.url, '_system');
```